# How could I mock the constructor of a node module with jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, github-actions

I've been learning jest and been doing ok so far but I've come up with something that I don't know how to resolve. I need to mock the @actions/github module and I think I've mocked the methods of the module the right way I think:

```
const githubListCommentsMock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
{
  id: 1,
  user: {login: 'github-actions[bot]'},
  body: 'Code quality reports: Mock value'
})
const githubDeleteCommentMock = jest.fn()
const githubCreateCommentMock = jest.fn()
const githubIssuesMock = { listComments: githubListCommentsMock,
    deleteComment: githubDeleteCommentMock,
    createComment: githubCreateCommentMock
  }
const githubContextMock = {repo:'Mocked Repository'}
jest.mock('@actions/github', () => ({
  Github:jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => (
     {issues: githubIssuesMock, context: githubContextMock}))
}))
```

But I have a piece of code on the file I'm testing that instances the github module like this:

```
const octokit = new github.GitHub(githubToken)
```

And my test fails when trying to execute the file with the following error:

```
TypeError: github.GitHub is not a constructor
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but I have also used that library. I got a hydrated github client using the function `getOctokit` and that is easy to mock/test.

Comment: I didn't find the `Github` constructor for https://www.npmjs.com/package/@actions/github package.

Answer (score 0):

Also been learning Jest and was having similar challenges. It is a little different to what you describe (and inline with the hydrated github client mentioned by M Mansour in the comments).

```
    // Setup stub Octokit to return from getOctokit.
    const StubOctokit = {
      search: {
        code: jest.fn()
      }
    }
    // Setup fake response from call to Octokit.search.code.
    const fakeResponse = {
      data: {
        total_count: 4
      }
    }
    // Code search should return fakeResponse.
    StubOctokit.search.code.mockReturnValueOnce(fakeResponse);
    // getOctokit should return the Octokit stub.
    github.getOctokit.mockReturnValueOnce(StubOctokit);
```

I'm sure there are likely much cleaner ways of doing it. After going round in circles for a while trying different approaches I ended up going step by step. Asserting getOctokit to have been called, using `mockReturnValueOnce` to set it an empty object, using `toHaveLastReturnedWith` and building up from there until getting the expected result.